# Pandas read_csv is retriving different data than what is in the text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a .txt (notepad) file called Log1.  It has the following saved in it: [1, 1, 1, 0]

When I write a program to retrieve the data:

```
Log1 = pd.read_csv('Path...\\Log1.txt')
Log1 = list(Log1)
print(Log1)
```

It prints: ['[1', ' 1', ' 1.1', ' 0]']

I dont understand where the ".1" is coming from on the third number.  Its not in the text file, it just adds it.

Funny enough if I change the numbers in the text file to: [1, 0, 1, 1].  It does not add the .1  It prints ['[1', ' 0', ' 1', ' 1]']

Very odd why its acting this way if anyone has an idea.

Comment: I think pandas is disambiguating your columns for you. It is not a good thing to be reading into a dataframe as it isn't well structured csv data, but anyway `[1, 1, 1, 0]` gets broken into four columns by *spaces* between the fields. So your columns are `[1` `1` `1` and `0]`. Since two of those columns have the same name, one of them gets a `.1` added to it. `[1, 0, 1, 1]` does not have that problem, as it is read as four columns that are all distinctly named, `[1` `0` `1` and `1]`

Comment: You can get slightly different (maybe better?) results if you add `header=None` to your read_csv() call.

Comment: @topsail  I see.  Maybe I should read the file without pandas and then convert into pandas after.  Or perhaps another dataframe is better.  I wrote and read to a .txt just because it seemed easy.  Any suggestion on a better structured dataframe?  I need to write lists to a file in one program and then retrieve it from another program.

Comment: Yes, that would work. There may be better ways - and other ways to save lists in python. The real question here is "How to serialize and deserialize a list in python".

Comment: I guess all the answers are here: https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/serialization/ (pick your poison :) )  Using json serialization is an old stand by I think.

Comment: I solved it with your guys input below.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I worked out some other options as well, just for the record:

Solution 1 (plain read - this one gets a list of string)

```
log4 = []
with open('log4.txt') as f:
    log4 = f.readlines()
print(log4)
```

Solution 2 (convert to list of ints)

```
import ast
with open('log4.txt', 'r') as f:
    inp = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
print(inp))
```

Solution 3 (old school string parsing - convert to list of ints, then put it in a dataframe)

```
with open('log4.txt', 'r') as f:
    mylist = f.read()

mylist = mylist.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(' ','')
mylist = mylist.split(',')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': mylist})
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].astype(int)
print(df)
```

Other ideas here as well:

https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/serialization/

In general the reading from the text file (deserializing) is easier if the text file is written in a good structured format in the first place - csv file, pickle file, json file, etc. In this case, using the `ast.literal_eval()` worked well since this was written out as a list using it's `__repr__` format -- though honestly I've never done that before so it was an interesting solution to me as well :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Can you please try this,

```
log2 = log1.values.tolist()
```

Output:

> [['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['0']]

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not in a CSV format.  In CSV you would rather have

```
1;1;0;1
```

or something similar.

If you have multiple lines like this, it might make sense to parse this as CSV, otherwise I'd rather parse it using a regexp and `.split` on the result.

Proposal: Add a bigger input example and your expected output.